# I compiled a assembly code on kali linux but i cant run it

Tags: linux, bash, assembly

I tried to run some code in **Kali** **Linux** in my kernel and it compiled but I cant run it. I followed some guys on *YouTube* and when I type **`ld hello.o -o hello`** it says that there is no `Ld command`!!
code is ok but I don't know how to run it. Btw I'm using *vim* and the *Kali Linux* is on my windows like it is not my main OS. if somebody can help me please help !

Comment: Kali Linux is a very minimal Linux intended only for penetration testing and is missing many tools - [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/56152)

Answer (score 4):

You need to install binutils as ld (the GNU Linker) is included in the binutils package.

On Kali, run the following on the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install binutils
```

Comment: Might as well grab all the `build-essential` packages while you're at it, but yeah that'll do for just assembling + linking.

Answer (score -7):

You are running your code on Vim. I think you should save it. I've run a C program this way. First, create a file with `vim filename.c`. Then, see which compiler it uses in Linux; for instance, in C it's `gcc`, and in Python it's `pip` or `python3 ./file name`, etc. Then, find what compiler your code wants, and install it in Linux. Run through that compiler, or you can simply download the Atom code editor, install the package, then run over there. I've done this on Vim and on Atom; it works both ways.

Comment: The lack of punctuation makes this extremely difficult to read.

Comment: Please read "[ask]"
"[Is it OK to downvote questions because of bad grammar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253780/128421)"
"[Priority of grammar, spelling and punctuation in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306797/128421)"

Comment: Sharad, as @Calculuswhiz notes, your answer is _very_ difficult to understand. I've edited in an _attempt_ to clarify your point by added punctuation, formatting, and some grammar fixes. Even then, however, I'm not entirely certain what you're suggesting. Can you review my edit to make sure it's consistent with your expectations, and then [edit] your answer further to ensure your suggestion is clear to readers.